# How to trigger 'click' event of on a file input in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

here is the view in `jade`:

```
button#save-csv-btn(ng-click="click()") Export CSV
input#save-csv(style="display:none", type="file", onchange="angular.element(this).scope().saveCSVFileChanged(this)")
```

js:

```
$scope.click = ->
    # $('#save-csv').trigger('click')
```

Error I get:

```
Error: $apply already in progress
```

Comment: You probably want to include the actual javascript here and the output from jade instead of the pre-processed code since more people will be able to help.  Generally this means you called $scope.$apply() within a function that is triggered during a $scope.$apply()

Comment: Also this seems generally like a bad idea, although you're not manipulating the DOM even assuming some element is there by name without using directives as your means to encapsulate that logic is not good.

Comment: This is quite a standard way of having a styled file input, by hiding the actual <input> and triggering click on it from another method.
the problem is that angular throws an error because it does an apply within an apply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea was to use button to 'emulate' the file input; I achieved this using http://gregpike.net/demos/bootstrap-file-input/demo.html.

```
input#save-csv(type="file", title="Export to CSV", onchange="angular.element(this).scope().saveCSVFileChanged(this)")
```

Answer (score 11):

I changed `$scope.click` function to trigger the input click in a `setTimeout`. This lets the first `$apply` finish, and then will trigger another one.

```
$scope.click = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        inputEl.click();
    }, 0);
}
```

Note that I use `setTimeout`, not `$timeout`. `$timeout` would also be inside an `$apply` block.

Comment: I had the same issue as OP, and using $timeout instead of setTimeout  worked for me as well

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this problem and have written a drop in solution. You can write a custom directive composed of a container, a button, and an input element with type file. With CSS you then place the input over the custom button but with opacity 0. You set the containers height and width to exactly the offset width and height of the button and the input's height and width to 100% of the container.

the directive

```
angular.module('myCoolApp')
  .directive('fileButton', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'components/directives/fileButton/fileButton.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

        var container = angular.element('.file-upload-container');
        var button = angular.element('.file-upload-button');

        container.css({
            position: 'relative',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            width: button.offsetWidth,
            height: button.offsetHeight
        })

      }

    };
  });
```

a jade template if you are using jade

```
div(class="file-upload-container") 
    button(class="file-upload-button") +
    input#file-upload(class="file-upload-input", type='file', onchange="doSomethingWhenFileIsSelected()")
```

the same template in html if you are using html

```
<div class="file-upload-container">
   <button class="file-upload-button"></button>
   <input class="file-upload-input" id="file-upload" type="file" onchange="doSomethingWhenFileIsSelected()" /> 
</div>
```

the css

```
.file-upload-button {
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 66px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 228, 0); 
    color: rgb(255, 228, 0);
}

.file-upload-input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```