# Trigger input file click event in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to emulate a click event on a file input in AngularJS. I have seen [working jQuery examples](http://jsfiddle.net/fEBFp/1/), but I don't want to use jQuery.

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('MyApp', []).

controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.click = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var element = angular.element(document.getElementById('input'));
      element.triggerHandler('click');
      $scope.clicked = true;
    }, 0);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input id="input" type="file"/>
  <button ng-click="click()">Click me!</button>
  <div ng-if="clicked">Clicked</div>
</div>
```

Note: For some reason the button needs to be pressed twice in order to trigger the timeout function.

I am using `setTimeout` because of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19519023/1154610).

How do I programmatically click a file input with just AngularJS / vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: The code in the question as well as the proposed answer is a well-known anti-pattern in Angular.js - don't do DOM manipulation in your controllers, unless it's in a directive controller.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can simply use

```
 <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('input').click()">Click me!</button>
```

OR

```
$scope.click = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('input').click()
        $scope.clicked = true;
    }, 0);
};
```

Comment: Hi, sometimes it's opened multiple times, any way to prevent that ?

Comment: I'm sure @LiadLivnat already solved his issue, but just in case anyone stumbles upon this and has the same issue; This happens when you put the `<input>` inside the element that's supposed to trigger the click on input.


`<div onClick="document.getElementById('input').click()"><input/></div>` will trigger infinite clicks on that element.


`<input/><div onClick="document.getElementById('input').click()"></div>` works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to **trigger file of type 'file'** or **open select-file window** when click on icon, button or span as you like ;)

css :

```
.attachImageForCommentsIcon{
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  outline:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

HTML :

```
<input id="myInput" type="file" style="visibility:hidden" ng-file-model=""/>
<i onclick="$('#myInput').click();" class="attachImageForCommentsIcon blue-2 right-position material-icons">image</i>
```

all credits goes for this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595389/programmatically-trigger-select-file-dialog-box

Thus, we **customized** file input tag using this way.

Comment: That looks like jQuery (OP doesn't want to use jQuery).